# Indexing from unique values from a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns and rows, and I want to get the data in one column based on the unique values in another column.

```
  flag  name
0  1     bob
1  2     larry
2  1     alice
3  1     mary
4  3     peter
5  4     rick
```

if a use

```
df['flag'].unique()
```

I get 1 2 3 4

How do I get the names that correspond to those unique values?

i.e.

```
  flag  name
0  1     bob
1  2     larry
4  3     peter
5  4     rick
```

It doesn't matter if I get bob, alice, or mary. I just need a name for that flag value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(['flag'])
Out[1036]: 
   flag   name
0     1    bob
1     2  larry
4     3  peter
5     4   rick
```

Comment: Thanks Wen! That's perfect. Is there a novel solution to getting the other names with the same flag value?

Comment: @EliotJackson you can check https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_delete_duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

Wen's answer is simpler, but another way is to use `groupby()` and then take the first entry per group using `nth()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'flag':[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4],
                   'name':['bob', 'larry', 'alice', 'mary', 'peter', 'rick']})

print df.groupby('flag').nth(0)
```

Result:

```
       name
flag       
1       bob
2     larry
3     peter
4      rick
```